# Database - Keep track of expenses monthly

Tags: php, database-design

I have the following database:

```
Clients(ClientID, ...)
Rooms(RoomID, ...)
Rents(RentID, ClientID, RoomID, StartDate, EndDate, Cost)
```

The cost is a monthly expense (paid every month). I want to keep track of every rent every month, starting when the application is created. As time goes by, the new months should be added.
How can I accomplish this?

Example: A rent starts in March with the cost of 200€. 3 months later I should have for this rent:

```
March - 200€
April - 200€
May - 200€
```

Consider that the cost of a rented room may change upon time, as well the rooms that a client has.

I have very little experience in designing databases so I don't have a good idea of how to do this.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

New months should be added **automatically**.

Let's say that in April I decide to change the cost to 300€. It should then show for this rent:

```
March - 200€
April - 300€
May - 300€
```

And if a client decides to change room, a new rent record will be created. In the end, I should be able to view all the expenses of a client.

Comment: Should rents for new months be added automatically or do you manually add a new one every month? How do you go about changing the cost?

Comment: Yes, automatically (I missed that word).
The cost would be changed by admin in the application whenever needed. I'm not sure where is the best place for it but I guess it's in the rent.

Comment: Would you specify a `StartDate` and `EndDate` each time you set the rent cost? Or could a cost potentially be open-ended and have no specified `EndDate`?

Comment: No. The StartDate is set when the rent is created and the EndDate is set when the rent is ended (when the client changes room or definitely leaves). The dates are supposed to give me a history of who has been in a specific room.

Comment: Active rents would have null EndDate.

Comment: I see. Are you picturing that, when you change the cost for an existing rental, it would set the `EndDate` for the current row and then insert a new row with a new `StartDate` and the new `Cost`?

Comment: No. Rents would be created only when a client enters a new room. Leaving a room simply sets the EndDate. Changing the cost would just be an Update to the cost value. This would however get recorded in the expenses history since in one month it would have the old cost and the next month would have the new cost. I'm open to better sugestions though.

Comment: You'll need a way to track cost changes. If you just update the row with a new cost, the old cost will be gone and all months will report the new cost. I was thinking a cost change could be considered a room change to the same room, but that might not be ideal. Perhaps a separate table to store the costs would work better. Regarding your question of how to display each month, do they need to be actual records in the database? Or can the monthly display be generated by PHP based on the start date and current date?

Comment: It should be possible to see the expenses from previous months. So I guess it has to be recorded. As for the cost, what I thought was to create the expense record in the end of the month so it would only have to copy the current value of cost. If the cost changes afterwards, the record for the previous month would keep the old cost.

Answer (score 2):

I might only document rent when I actually receive it, rather than generating records automatically.

But to automatically generate records, consider storing only the timestamped cost changes and then generating monthly tracking in PHP. You could determine the cost for any given date by finding the latest cost change in the database relative to that date. I'd store the cost changes in a separate table, along with the `RentID`.

However, if you want to insert a database row for each month, here's one idea:

---

Consider creating a separate table for expense history. The `Rents` table will have one row per client/room and the `History` table would contain a row for each client/room per month.

Add necessary records to the `History` table whenever they are requested for display. For example, say you create a client's rental in January. When you check their history in May, the system would insert any necessary records for February, March, April, and May before displaying the list.

When you change the cost, it would update the `Rents` row for that client/room. That new cost would be used for subsequent `History` rows.

I don't know which type of database you're using or how you're accessing it, so I'll demonstrate by hard-coding the database values:

```
<?php

// Fetch the latest `Rents` rows for a particular `ClientID` and `RoomId`.
// $latest = $db->fetch(...);

$latest = [
   'startDate'=>'2019-11-25',
   'cost'=> 200
];

// Define the start date and current date
$startDate = new DateTime($latest['startDate']);
$currentDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

// define monthly interval and periods
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$periods = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $currentDate);

// interate through periods ...
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    // ... and insert a new record with the date from $period and cost from $latest
    $records[] = ['date'=>$period->format('Y-m-d'),'cost'=>$latest['cost']];
}

// Fetch and display all `Rents` rows for that `ClientID` and `RoomId`
echo "<pre>".print_r($records,true)."</pre>";
```

Example of what's inserted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-11-25
            [cost] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-12-25
            [cost] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-01-25
            [cost] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-02-25
            [cost] => 200
        )

)
```

Comment: There is a separate system for processing the payments, this one only has the monthly value for general reading purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a possible solution but it's not properly what I'm looking for. I would want to have the rent cost added to the db every month. I thought I could have a script to add the records and have it executed in the 1st day of the month with cron job. I'm just not sure about the db table structure. Would something like the following work? Expenses(ExpenseID, ClientID, RoomID, Cost, Date). I'm not sure how to go about the date.